# Close current form with dynamic event from dynamic linklabel

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello i have a method generating linklabels dynamically, once you click on the dynamic label, it shall open another form and close the current one. i have been able to open the other form, but i cannot find the code "this.close()" from my dynamic event. Here is my code:

```
 public void xxx(){

 // codes to generate linklabels ...etc 

  lnklbl1.Click += (sender, e) =>
              {
                  try
                  {

                      new frmTest().Show();
                     //this.Close();  <---- what am not being able to do

                  }
                  catch (Exception ex)
                  {
                      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                  }
                  // MessageBox.Show(answerIndex.ToString());
              };
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You're going to need to show more code.  If the snippet you showed is being defined from within the form you want to close it should work just fine.

Comment: thanks, i found the mistake and it was a stupid one, the method was in another class, so i just added a Form aaa in the parameters and did aaa.Close() and it worked. Thanks a lot though :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not close it , perhaps you should rather set its visibility to false.
Form2 was created inside Form1, if you close Form1 that would close Form2 as well.

```
this.Visible = false;
```

Comment: nop sorry this is not working, when i type this, i cannot find .visible, .close, ...

Comment: thanks still for your reply, i found the mistake, i could not do this.visible... because my method was in another class and not in the form , its fine now :)